# Implementation of a simple file transfer client server

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

Hi I have the following code to the client - server through the thread, I have a  errors,

Can't setup server on this port number.

Can't setup server on this port number.

but why?

class client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

// create class client
public class Client extends Thread {

Socket socket = null;
Socket socket1 = null;
 // create send method 
public  void sendFile() throws IOException {

String host = "127.0.0.1";
String host1 = "127.0.0.2";

socket = new Socket(host, 4444);
socket1 = new Socket(host1, 444);

File file = new File("/home/reza/Desktop/link help");
File file1 = new File("/home/reza/Desktop/hi");
long length = file.length();
long length1 = file1.length();
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];
byte[] bytes1 = new byte[(int) length1];

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(file1);

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
BufferedInputStream bis1 = new BufferedInputStream(fis1);
BufferedOutputStream out1 = new BufferedOutputStream(socket1.getOutputStream());

int count;
int count1;


  while ((count = bis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
    out.write(bytes, 0, count);

}
 while ((count1 = bis1.read(bytes1)) > 0) {
    out1.write(bytes1, 0, count1);

}


 Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {



 public void run()
 {
  while(socket.isConnected())
  {

 Wait2();


   try {
 sendFile();
 } catch (IOException e) {

e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
 }
 });

 Thread t1 = new Thread(new  Runnable() {
 public void run() {
 while(socket1.isConnected())
    {

     Wait2();


       try {
    sendFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

   }
  });
  t.start();
  t1.start();

 fis.close();
 fis1.close();

 out.close();
 bis.close();
 out1.close();
 bis1.close();
 socket.close();
 socket1.close();
 }

  public void Wait2()

 {


  try {

  Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);

   } catch (InterruptedException x) {

  System.out.println("Interrupted!");

   }

   }
  }
```

// class server

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.net.*;
  public class Server {




public  void recivefile() throws IOException {
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
ServerSocket serverSocket1 = null;


try {

   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
   //serverSocket1 = new ServerSocket(444);

} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Can't setup server on this port number. ");
}
try {
     serverSocket1 = new ServerSocket(444);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Can't setup server on this port number. ");
    }


Socket socket = null;
Socket socket1 = null;

InputStream is = null;
InputStream is1 = null;

FileOutputStream fos = null;
FileOutputStream fos1 = null;

BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
BufferedOutputStream bos1 = null;

int bufferSize = 0;
int bufferSize1 = 0;


try {
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
   socket1 = serverSocket1.accept();




} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Can't accept client connection. ");
}

try {
    is = socket.getInputStream();
    is1 = socket1.getInputStream();


    bufferSize = socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
    bufferSize1 = socket1.getReceiveBufferSize();

    System.out.println("Buffer size: " + bufferSize);
    System.out.println("file recieved");
    System.out.println("Buffer size1: " + bufferSize1);
    System.out.println("file recieved");

    System.out.println("file recieved");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Can't get socket input stream. ");
}


try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream("/home/reza/Desktop/reza");
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    fos1 = new FileOutputStream("/home/reza/Desktop/ali");
    bos1 = new BufferedOutputStream(fos1);



} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("File not found. ");
}

byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

int count;

while ((count = is.read(bytes)) > 0) {
   bos.write(bytes, 0, count);

}
byte[] bytes1 = new byte[bufferSize1];

int count1;
while ((count1 = is1.read(bytes1)) > 0) {
       bos1.write(bytes1, 0, count1);
    }


bos.flush();
bos.close();
bos1.flush();
bos1.close();
is.close();
is1.close();
socket.close();
serverSocket.close();
socket1.close();
serverSocket1.close();

}

public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException 
{
System.out.println("server is run, please send file");



Server s = new Server();
s.recivefile();


}
}
```

error is : 
Can't setup server on this port number. 
Can't setup server on this port number.

Comment: 1) way too much code - all your file stuff is extraneous to the failure 2) Change your error code so that you know which ServerSocket is not being opened - hint, why open serverSocket1 twice?

Answer (score 1):

You can't start a server on 127.0.0.2 - therein lies your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code runs on a unix platform, your server code is trying twice to open a socket on port 444, which is a system reserved port. In order to be able to succeed, your programme must run with administrative priviledges, and you must ensure that the port is not already used by another process.

A possible workaround is to:

- use a port above 1024. These ports are free to use for userland programmes
- in case of failure have a backup port, also above 1024. You must amend both server and client codes to try both ports, and of course your communication protocol must include some form of handshaking to make sure they are talking to the right interlocutor.

There are many other problems with your code listed in other answers.

- you don't need to make every objects twice. Only one instance is enough in most cases,
- if your server is running continuously and must accept many connections, you should not close the accepting socket at the end of one receiving session.
- also the server is supposed to run a loop on the server socket accept call, and start a new thread for each incoming connection, whose job is to handle that connection.

While I understand your willingness to learn and experiment, there are existing solutions to what you are trying to achieve. For instance, you could simply use a FTP server for your purpose.

Comment: i change code, i have used in above code two port for two client,and i have change port of 4444 to 1024 and another port of 444 to 1025. that error resolved,After sending a file, the following error is repeated continuously: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused and other same erro please help me

Comment: reza, this is not the way this website works: if my answer fixed your problem, you should have indicated that somehow: either by marking my answer as correct, or at least by updating your question to say that the port problem is solved and now you have a different problem. The way you are currently doing, everyone think that 1024 is the port causing you problems.

Answer (score 0):

**netstat -ano | find "1024"**

try above command if you are running your java files on windows environment that will help you to find any process using same port no as yours and also use 
ex.printStackTrace() along with

```
System.out.println("Can't setup server on this port number.");
```

Comment: i work in linux(ubuntu),that error resolved,After sending a file, the following error is repeated continuously: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused and other same erro please help me

Comment: can you put debug statements like :
    "Coming from this method <MethodName>" etc..
in you code so that we can find out from which code block you are getting this error ?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written client - server program is wrong I guess.
Following are the mistakes you have done...

1) In Client class, you have `sendFile` function in which you've created two threads - `t` &   `t1`. In run function you are again calling the same `sendFile` function.
So it keeps creating threads under threads just like recursion.

2) In Server class, you are listening to two port within the same `recieveFile` function. As the `socket = serverSocket.accept()` is a blocking call, It wont excecute the rest of the code untill it finds a single client to connect.

So what exactly happens here is.. Once the first client connects, thenafter immediately it expects second client to connect. 
In the mean time your client thread may try to access the port on which connection has not been established.

In short, your SERVER SHOULD BE IN A THREADING ENVIRONMENT NOT THE CLIENT.
And I would suggest that for different port you should use different server.
i.e. create different server class for both 1024 & 1025 port.